# Using APM in a .NET Console app, can I force send data to APM server?

Tags: .net, elastic-stack, elastic-apm

I'm trying to monitor a console app (automatically run every hour) in .NET

The app is built on an HostBuilder, I have called `.UseAllElasticApm()` and `.UseConsoleLifetime()` on it, and I make a transaction by code :

```cs
var transaction = Elastic.Apm.Agent.Tracer.StartTransaction("ConsoleAppRunning", ApiConstants.TypeRequest);

try {
    await RunCode();
}
catch (Exception ex){
    transaction.CaptureException(ex);
}
finally{
    transaction.End();
}
```

The app closes just after the `finally`.

This code worked on my dev machine, and I could see data appear on APM.

But once built in Release mode and deployed to Production server, I could see the service in Kibana with Environment Production, but no data in it.

After searching a while, I think the problem is the [flush interval](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/dotnet/current/config-reporter.html#config-flush-interval) set to 30s by default

I changed the value to 1s, and added a `Task.Delay` at the end of the console app, and now I see the transactions in Kibana.

But I don't like this solution, isn't there a way to force flush when I know my app is about to close, and wait for it to be done ?